# how to declare pointer type in flatbuffers schema file?

Tags: c, schema, flatbuffers

I am learning flatbuffers and I wish to use them in C.
What I'm trying to do is writing a schema file for my structs. 
this is one of my structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short request_number;
    unsigned short length;
    unsigned short height;
    unsigned char   *buffer;
} CASH_RECEIPT_REQUEST;
```

How can i write the pointer `unsigned char *buffer` in my schema file?

Comment: What do you mean by How can write the schema file ?

Comment: @yadhu
I mean something like this that i should write in the fbs file:
table CASH_RECEIPT_REQUEST{
    request_number:byte;
    length:byte;
    height:byte;
    buffer: ???
}

Comment: Pointer sizes are platform dependent, for 64 bit processor you can define it as unsigned long long, Since the size of pointer and ulong (in schema) are same. At the parsing size typecast the value to pointer type. If this helps. I will post this as answer.

Comment: @yadhu
yes I think this will work
thank you!

Comment: Can you accept the answer? then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pointer sizes are platform dependent. If you decide use it on 64-bit processor with 8 bytes size pointers you can use ulong (as schema specifies in [here](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__schemas.html)) ulong size is 8 bytes. So at the parsing side you can typecast the ulong (In other words unsigned long) to char* type to obtain the correct pointer value.
Sample schema for your example looks like this

```
CASH_RECEIPT_REQUEST {
  request_number:ushort;
  length:ushort;
  height:ushort;
  buffer:ulong;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not a very good answer.. you never want to write the pointer value, you want to write the actual data it points to. The pointer will have no meaning when you load this back in. FlatBuffers will create the equivalent of pointers for you using offsets automatically.

Comment: Do think representing  a whole array in schema is better solution?

Comment: yadhu: it is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store pointers, instead store the actual data they point to:

```
table CashReceiptRequest {
  request_number:ushort;
  length:ushort;
  height:ushort;
  buffer:[ubyte];      
}
```

The buffer is a "vector of ubyte", as you can see. Note that if `length` is the size of the buffer, that field can be omitted, since the size is already stored as part of the vector.